# How to merge table cells in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to merge two cells of a table in mediawiki like so:

Current table:

| hello | world |
| --- | --- |
| one | col |

Goal:
Merge the two cells "one" and "col"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this excellent resource online where all the mediawiki table markup is explained: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Sorting#Background_colors_in_sortable_headers

My solution was the following:

```
{|-
|Hello
|World
|-
| colspan="2" | one col
|-
|}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you have found is good and if you edit cells via VisualEditor you just select cells you'd like to merge, and pop-up window appears. There you can click on merge and they merge.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I used my table in a template where I did not have the VisualEditor. However I did not know that VisualEditor offers this feature.